# Prestashop: issue with conditional statements in tpl file (PHP, Smarty)

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

I'm struggling to achieve this:

- Display a conditional voucher in the order confirmation page.
- The voucher is related with two required conditions: the order's
  weight and if the user has an account

So I'm working with the following file: /public_html/themes/mytheme/templates/checkout/order-confirmation.tpl. I've tried this so far:

```
{if ($order.shipping_weight >= 1.00) && ($logged)}
    <div class="5-percent-voucher">Voucher</div>
{elseif ($order.shipping_weight >= 2.00) && ($logged)}
    <div class="10-percent-voucher">Voucher</div>
{else}
{/if}
```

The good news is that the page doesn't crash. The bad news is that nothing is displayed when I simulate a checkout that fulfills the conditions.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in 1.7 you don't have `$logged`, you need to use `$customer.is_logged` :)

Comment: Hi Krystian! Thank you for your response. Your comment worked fine for me!